# facebook test user query only return 25 test users each time?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using the method described here to query all test users I created :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/app/accounts/test-users

However, I found each time I could only get 25 users shown in results.
But I failed to find any documentation to state this limitation.

Am I missing anything here?

Thanks

Derek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the default limit is 25. But if you specify a parameter "limit",  you can get as many test users returned as you want.

Here is the syntax:

```
/appID/accounts/test-users?limit=100  --> return 100 test users if existing.
/appID/accounts/test-users?limit=2000  --> you can return at most 2000 test users if existing.
```

Comment: I created a package to automate this procedure: https://github.com/gepolv/fb-zombie